# Как решить проблему со звуком в Debian 9?

Tags: linux, debian

Доброго времени суток,

На днях переустановил Debian на ПК с 8-ой на 9-ую версию и наткнулся на проблему со звуком. Точнее на отсутствие звука (ранее всё было прекрасно). После долгих манипуляций всё таки получилось включить звук, но вот качество звука хуже чем было раньше. Сейчас, когда слушаешь через наушники более получаса начинает "давить" на уши.

В PulseAudio в **Конфигурация** выставил **Аналоговый стерео выход (unplugged)**, в разделе **Устройства Вывода** выставил Port: **Аналоговые наушники (unplugged)**.

После этих настроек звук появился, но качество плохое...И после перезагрузки ПК звук снова пропадает, приходится постоянно заходить в PulseAudio и менять настройки.
Что можно сделать? Ранее проблем со звуком не было и качество было хорошее. Наушники подключал к телефону, качество хорошее

Comment: у меня такое было при обрыве кабеля. общий провод.

Comment: да нет, это всё проверил. думаю это всё в настройках можно сделать (лишь догадка), но вот как правильно настраивать частоты и т.п. я, к сожалению, не знаю

Comment: Прочитайте 500 страничный мануал по pulseaudio, навечно ваш Поттеринг!

Comment: Отключить звук. Нет звука - нет проблем со звуком. И вообще для аудиофилов выпускаются специальные устройства. Не стоит ожидать от компьютера что-то лучше пищалки. Тем более от линуха.

Answer (score 1):

Debian 9.3 звук был плохой. Я включил динамики в гнездо наушников очень помогло.

Comment: Похоже на обрыв в разъеме или перегруз по входу. Запусти alsamixer, там выбирай физическую звуковуху в устройствах и попробуй сделать потише :помогло? - перегруз. Попробуй сдвинуть баланс на лево или направо: качество улучшается - ушатался разъем.